# How to upload images from react native to nodejs?

Tags: node.js, react-native, upload

I'm trying to upload an image with expo picker image to a nodejs server.
The problem is I never receive the image. I tried so many things I'm desesperate :(

Here is my code :

React-Native

```
  postImage = async (image) => {
    const photo = {
      uri: image.uri,
      type: "image/jpg",
      name: "photo.jpg",
    };

    const form = new FormData();

    form.append("test", photo);

    axios.post(
      url,
      {
        body: form,
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg',
        }
      }
    )
    .then((responseData) => {
      console.log("Succes "+ responseData)
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log("ERROR " + error)
    });
  }

  pickImage = async () => {
    const result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      // mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
      // allowsEditing: true,
      // aspect: [4, 3],
      quality: 1
    });

    if (!result.cancelled) {
      try {
        await this.postImage(result);
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
      }

      this.setState({ image: result.uri });
    }
  };
```

It always works.

And here the nodejs code

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cors = require("cors");
const multer = require('multer');
const fs = require("fs");

const app = express();
const upload = multer({ 
  dest: "upload/",
});

// app.use(upload.single("test"));

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());
app.listen(8080, () => {
  console.log("running ...")
})

app.post("/upload", upload.single("photo.jpg"), async (req, res) => {
  console.log("body =>", req.body);
  console.log('files => ', req.files);
  console.log("file =>", req.file);

  // const oldpath = req.body.;
  // const newpath = '/Users/mperrin/test/test-native/test-upload-photo/server/lol.jpg';

  // fs.rename(oldpath, newpath, (err) => {
  //   if (err) {
  //     throw err;
  //   }

  //   res.write('File uploaded and moved!');
  //   res.sendStatus(200);
  // });

  res.sendStatus(200);
});
```

I always see this in the console and I don't know what to do with that ...

```
body => {
  body: { _parts: [ [Array] ] },
  headers: { 'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg' }
}
```

At the moment only the folder "upload" is created.
I don't know where I can get the files, I guess I'm really missing something but I don't know what.

Thanks for help guys !

Comment: see answer below

Comment: did you get the answer ?

Answer (score 0):

I've never used multer before but after a quick review of the docs it looks like you need to have the same name in the headers as you're expecting in the node side post

Right now, in your header you have

```
    name: 'photo.jpg'
```

and the following in your node post

```
    upload.single("test")
```

Your post is looking for something with the name 'test' not 'photo.jpg' and you're sending 'photo.jpg'

Try it out and let me know how it goes.

Edit: My mistake, you may have add 
        name: "test"

to the headers here instead of in the photo object:

```
    axios.post(
          url,
          {
            body: form,
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg',
            }
          })
```

Comment: Hello !

I change the name in the nodejs code "test" by "photo.jpg" and I got the same result !

I update my initial post !

thanks ;)

Comment: Any other idea ?

Comment: try taking a look at this https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/file-upload-with-multer-in-node--cms-32088

Comment: I found the solution,

It just doesnt work with axios, i instead used fetch and it worked ;)